# Selecting a single id by most recent date [MYSQL][PHP]

Tags: mysql, date, select

should be a simple one for you smart peoples.

Im trying to get a single `id` (`integer`) from a `select` statement by the most recent date/time stamp and where 'id = pupil_id'.

this is the table

so if i had

```
order_id | date_bought         | pupil_id
-----------------------------------------
14       | 2013-03-07 21:50:00 | aaa1111
15       | 2013-03-07 21:55:00 | bbb1111
```

so from this set of data the value i want is 15.

then how do i put this into a php variable, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT order_id FROM table ORDER BY date_bought DESC LIMIT 1
```

As for putting it into PHP, what are you using to connect to MySQL? PDO, MySQLi, or the old API?

Comment: THANK YOU, i used part of your answer, i didnt explain what i wanted well, but thanks man!!!!!!!!!!!!!!